# plotting data read from .txt file with respect to timestamp in octave

Tags: plot, text, timestamp, time-series, octave

I have a text (.txt) file which have data in the below format. How do I plot parameters w.r.t timestamp ? i am new in Octave.

```
timestamp          parameter 1       parameter 2
10:31:35.145         -7.28          -0.34   
10:31:35.146        -11.95          -17.84
```

Comment: have a look at strftime and strptime to convert your timestamps to suitable numbers

Comment: Code snippets would be much more helpful as I have started programming recently. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Only as I can see that is a nasty issue for a beginner.

First: Put your data in a text file without the header before starting octave

```
$ cat data.txt
10:31:35.145         -7.28          -0.34
10:31:35.146        -11.95          -17.84
```

Second: from within octave

open the file and store the file descriptor

```
> D=fopen("data.txt")
D =  4
```

store the data in a cell Array specifing all the data format as the time separator is a problem

```
> A=textscan(D,"%f:%f:%f\t%f\t%f");
```

convert the hours, minutes, seconds in a single vector; store the other data in other two vectors

```
> timestamp=A{1}*3600+A{2}*60+A{3}
timestamp =

   37895.14500
   37895.14600

> parameter1=A{4}
parameter1 =

   -7.2800
  -11.9500

> parameter2=A{5}
parameter2 =

   -0.34000
  -17.84000
```

choose a graphic toolkit (fltk is not working well on my platform)
and plot the data

```
> graphics_toolkit("gnuplot")
> plot(timestamp,parameter1,timestamp,parameter2)
```

[image]

Comment: Corrected the typo. What about read the manual anyway ? https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Introduction-to-Plotting.html#Introduction-to-Plotting and https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Graphics-Toolkits.html#Graphics-Toolkits

Comment: Thanks a lot, btw why are we using fopen and can textscan be replaced with dlmread ?

Comment: only if your time data was not expressed like that but with a single number